# 2 2-dimensional Brownian motions are close to each other

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Suppose $B^1$ is a standard 2 dimensional Brownian motion and $B^2$ is a 2 dimensional Brownian motion with mean zero and covariance matrix $\Gamma =
\begin{pmatrix}
  a & b \\
  b & a \\
\end{pmatrix}   $, both defined in the same probability space $(\Sigma, A, P)$. I would like to know how I can estimate $P(\sup\{ | B^1_{t} -  B^2_{t}  |, t \in [0,T] \} > \epsilon) $?

Comment: is this about Monte Carlo computations, or are you looking for a closed form solution?

Comment: No, it is not Monte Carlo computations, I want to estimate this theoretically.

Comment: If $B^2$ is independent of $B^1$, $B^2-B^1$ is a centered gaussian process with known covariance.